# failed to shutdown container in docker:

Tags: windows, docker, containers

when im trying to build an image with command docker build im getting this error

im using windows docker desktop

The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install --production' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295: failed to shutdown container: container 1842716825b498d7be9ed514a4839dfc528caafe8f906018c93842517f60635e encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110): subsequent terminate failed container 1842716825b498d7be9ed514a4839dfc528caafe8f906018c93842517f60635e encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110)

how this error be resolved

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This must be due to windows host failure on docker call when try to shut down the container

Try by restarting  docker demon

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Check the status of the Docker containers:

```
docker ps -a
```

stop and remove it:

```
docker stop <container-id>
docker rm <container-id>
```

Then try by building the image again. If the problem still persists, consider upgrading to the latest version of Docker or clear docker cache or

```
docker system prune
```